# how to proceed with low-level-calls detected by slither

Tags: slither

I have a low level call in my smart contract

```
    (bool success, ) = address.call{ value: amount * percentage / 100 }("");
    require(success, "some error");
```

and is detected by slither.

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/.../path/.../MyContract.sol",
    "owner": "Slither",
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "Low level call in MyContract.function(string,uint8) (contracts/MyContract.sol#341-365):\n\t- (success) = address.call{value: amount * percentage / 100}() (contracts/MyContract.sol#353)",
    "startLineNumber": 341,
    "startColumn": 2,
    "endLineNumber": 342,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
```

The call is supposed to send ether to another smart contract fallback function. Whereas this is the recommended way by solidity to call fallback function, Slither hits a positive here.

https://solidity-by-example.org/call/

**This is the recommended method to use when you're just sending Ether via calling the fallback function.**

So, in order to remove the positive from audit reports, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

To ignore a finding, you can manually add a comment indicating that  the next row should be disregarded

```
//slither-disable-next-line low-level-calls
(bool success, ) = address.call{ value: amount * percentage / 100 }("");
require(success, "some error");
```

or by running Slither in triage mode

```bash
slither . --triage-mode
```

and idenfying all false positives. More details can be found in [the docs](https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Usage#triage-mode).